# pandas: checking if all given values are in index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, isin

I have several pandas data frames with different indexes. Lets say for this example I have indexes  from 50  to 200, how can I check if all three given numbers for example [10, 51, 99] are within that index? (I need this for validation purposes to return errors if an index can't be called)

My idea was to use .isin() but with .any() as in the example below it only checks whether any of the values occur in the index. Is there an option to check whether ALL indexes occur?
It should return True if all values occur and False as soon as one value doesn't occur.

```py
df.index.isin([10,51,99]).any()
```

Comment: `all(x in df.index for x in [10,51,99])`? or `set([10,51,99]).issubset(df.index)`

Comment: use all instead of any?

Comment: @NathanFurnal - No that will just check if every value in the index is in that list

Comment: @not_speshal Yes, that seems to work. Thank you a lot. Is it also as efficient or is there a more efficient option (no iteration)?

Comment: `issubset` is efficient

Comment: @janbo It will convert it to a set first.

Comment: @janbo - Please see my first comment. It already shows you how to do what you want. To repeat: `set([10,51,99]).issubset(df.index)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sum()`.

`isin(..)` returns a `bool` array, and `sum()` basically returns the count of `True` elements.

So, in your case, you should check if `sum()` is equal to the length of `values` you pass in:

```py
df.index.isin([10,51,99]).sum() == 3
```

If we generalize:

```py
df.index.isin(values).sum() == len(values)
```

**Note:** As mentioned by *Joooeey* in the below comment, this will only work if the index does not contain duplicates.

Comment: This only works if you know that the index does not contain duplicates.

Comment: Correct, good catch, edited the answer to mention this.